# Resetting dropdown box to original value in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown

Hello I am working in react and am fairly new to it, I am working to reset the field values to its original state after a user has submitted an athlete (after clicking the create record button) and I want the dropdown text box to return to "Other" if a user has changed the field to something else. So for example.
First Name: "John",
Last Name: "Smith",
Sport: "Men's Golf" would reset to

First Name: "",
Last Name: "",
Sport: "Other"
I've managed to reset all the other fields but the sport dropdown field isn't resetting and I have no clue why. Here is the code I'm working with.

```
import React from "react";
import "./athleteEntryStyle.css";
import { baseUrl } from "../../serviceConfig";

interface Props {
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
  dominant_foot?: string;
  preferred_name?: string;
  position?: string;
  firstName: string;
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  sport: string;
}

interface State {
  username?: string;
  password?: string;
  dominant_foot?: string;
  preferred_name?: string;
  position?: string;
  firstName: string;
  middleName: string;
  lastName: string;
  phone: string;
  email: string;
  dateOfBirth: string;
  sport: string;
}

export class AthleteEntry extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: props.username,
      password: props.password,
      dominant_foot: props.dominant_foot,
      preferred_name: props.preferred_name,
      position: props.position,
      firstName: props.firstName,
      middleName: props.middleName,
      lastName: props.lastName,
      phone: props.phone,
      email: props.email,
      dateOfBirth: props.dateOfBirth,
      sport: props.sport,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event: { target: any }) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;
    console.log(target);
    console.log(value);
    console.log(name);
    const newState = { [name]: value } as Pick<Props, keyof State>;
    this.setState(newState);
    
  }

  handleSubmit(event: { preventDefault: () => void }) {
    const request = JSON.stringify({
      username: this.state.username,
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password,
      first_name: this.state.firstName,
      middle_name: this.state.middleName,
      last_name: this.state.lastName,
      phone_number: this.state.phone?.toString(),
      dominant_foot: this.state.dominant_foot,
      sport: this.state.sport,
      position: this.state.position,
      preferred_name: this.state.preferred_name,
      date_of_birth: new Date(this.state.dateOfBirth).toISOString(),
    });

    console.log("Request from app");
    console.log(request);

    const requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: request,
    };
    this.setState({firstName: "", middleName: "", lastName: "", preferred_name: "", dateOfBirth: "date", phone: "", email: "", 
    username: "", password: "", dominant_foot: "", sport: "Other", position: "" });
    //NOTE: This is assuming your service instance is running locally, we have to either make a config file that allows you to switch this as necessary or
    //switch this to the hosted service when that becomes a thing
    fetch(baseUrl + "athlete/create", requestOptions).then(function (response) {
      if (response.status == 201) {
        alert("An athlete was successfully created.");
      } else {
        alert(
          "Error creating athlete: API responded with code " +
            response.status.toString()
        );
      }
    });
    event.preventDefault();

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        className="form"
        onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          padding: "20px",
          height: "100vh",
          background: "linear-gradient(#fff, #d00000)",
        }}
      >
        <div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">First Name:</label>
            <input
              name="firstName"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.firstName}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Middle Name:</label>
            <input
              name="middleName"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.middleName}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Last Name:</label>
            <input
              name="lastName"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.lastName}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Preferred Name:</label>
            <input
              name="preferred_name"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.preferred_name}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Date of Birth:</label>
            <input
              name="dateOfBirth"
              className="input"
              type="date"
              value={this.state.dateOfBirth}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Phone Number:</label>
            <input
              name="phone"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.phone}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Email:</label>
            <input
              name="email"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.email}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Username:</label>
            <input
              name="username"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Password:</label>
            <input
              name="password"
              className="input"
              type="password"
              value={this.state.password}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Dominant Foot:</label>
            <input
              name="dominant_foot"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.dominant_foot}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Sport:</label>
            {/* <input
              name="sport"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.sport}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            /> */}
            <select
              name="sport"
              className="input"
              id="sport"
              defaultValue="Other"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              <option value="Football (MFB)">Football (MFB)</option>
              <option value="Baseball (MBA)">Baseball (MBA)</option>
              <option value="Softball (WSB)">Softball (WSB)</option>
              <option value="Men's Basketball (MBB)">
                Men's Basketball (MBB)
              </option>
              <option value="Women's Basketball (WBB)">
                Women's Basketball (WBB)
              </option>
              <option value="Men's Cross Country (MCC)">
                Men's Cross Country (MCC)
              </option>
              <option value="Women's Cross Country (WCC)">
                Women's Cross Country (WCC)
              </option>
              <option value="Men's Golf (MGO)">Men's Golf (MGO)</option>
              <option value="Women's Golf (WGO)">Women's Golf (WGO)</option>
              <option value="Women's Soccer (WSO)">Women's Soccer (WSO)</option>
              <option value="Women's Volleyball (WVB)">
                Women's Volleyball (WVB)
              </option>
              <option value="Women’s Bowling (WBW)">
                Women’s Bowling (WBW)
              </option>
              <option value="Men’s Gymnastics (MGY)">
                Men’s Gymnastics (MGY)
              </option>
              <option value="Women’s Gymnastics (WGY)">
                Women’s Gymnastics (WGY)
              </option>
              <option value="Women’s Swimming/Diving (WSW)">
                Women’s Swimming/Diving (WSW)
              </option>
              <option value="Men’s Tennis (MTE)">Men’s Tennis (MTE)</option>
              <option value="Women’s Tennis (WTE)">Women’s Tennis (WTE)</option>
              <option value="Men’s Wrestling (MWR)">
                Men’s Wrestling (MWR)
              </option>
              <option value="Women’s Rifle (WRI)">Women’s Rifle (WRI)</option>
              <option value="Women’s Track (WTO)">Women’s Track (WTO)</option>
              <option value="Men’s Track (MTO)">Men’s Track (MTO)</option>
              <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div style={styles}>
            <label className="label">Position:</label>
            <input
              name="position"
              className="input"
              type="text"
              value={this.state.position}
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div style={{ marginBottom: 12, padding: 10 }}>
            <label>
              <input type="submit" value="Create Record" className="button"/>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
const styles = {
  marginBottom: 12,
};
```

Most of the code above won't matter to you except the line where the change is made. So

```
this.setState({firstName: "", middleName: "", lastName: "", preferred_name: "", dateOfBirth: "date", phone: "", email: "", 
    username: "", password: "", dominant_foot: "", sport: "Other", position: "" });
```

is where the change is being made.

Comment: You are almost there. Just set the state you want within this block `if (response.status == 201) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have `defaultValue="Other"` as a prop in your `select` component, but what you really want is `value={this.state.sport}`, like you have in the commented out `input` above it.  This will make it a controlled component, so the value of that select field will be based on your state.  The other fields are done that way, looks like it may have just been an oversight.

Comment: Also, as a side note, we generally don't want to derive our component's state from props passed to it. Usually fixing that just requires a little refactoring/thinking about the component a little differently.  Here's a helpful blog post from the React team about derived state https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Comment: after trying this it works but I need the defaultValue to be set to Option when the page is initially loaded up. When it is set to  value={this.state.sport} the first option which is Football comes up first. Even when something like both defaultValue and value are used value seems to overwrite defaultValue

Comment: Try `this.state = {
     // everything else
      sport: "Other",
    };` when you're setting the initial state in the constructor

Comment: That's part of the issue with derived state, for a quick fix, I'd say make sure your passing the `sport` prop as `"Other"`, but in the long run it will be better to refactor so the state isn't based on the props passed down to the component